UMVUE for $\rho$
Given $X=\left( X_{1},\cdots, X_{n}\right)$ and $X\sim N\left( 0,\Sigma \right)$, where
$$
\Sigma=\sigma^{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&\rho&\cdots &\rho\\ \rho &1&\cdots &\rho\\ \vdots &\vdots &&\vdots\\ \rho &\rho&\cdots &1
\end{pmatrix}
,\rho\in\left( -1,1 \right),
$$
how can I find out the UMVUE for $\rho$?
I have found the UMVUE of $\sigma^{2}$ and $\rho\sigma^2$, but I don't know how to get the UMVUE for $\rho$.
I proved that $\left( X^{\prime}X,X^{\prime}JX \right)$ ($J$ is the all-ones matrix) is the complete and sufficient statistic for $\left( \rho,\sigma^{2} \right)$, and I found that $X^{\prime}\left( I-\dfrac{1}{n}J \right)X$ and $X^{\prime}JX$ are independent. So I guess the UMVUE of $\rho$ may be relevant to $T\left( X \right)=\dfrac{X^{\prime}\left( I-\dfrac{1}{n}J \right)X}{X^{\prime}JX}$. But I don't know how to solve $\operatorname E T\left( X \right)$, so I cannot verify whether my conjecture is correct or not.

What's an "UMVUE"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator

I'm not sure you can be sure that any UMVUE exists, but I haven't thought about the details yet.

Given that the expected value is the same for all distributions in this paramaterized family, the sample covarience matrix would have a Wishart distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom rather than $n-1.$ If I'm not mistaken, it would be be an unbiased estimator of $\Sigma.$ But the sample covariance matrix could have off-diagonal entries differing from each other, in which case it would not among the possible values of $\Sigma$ and would not be the MLE. But if you find its conditional expected value given your complete sufficient statistic, what do you get?

ok, Thinking first about the MLE for $\sigma^2,\rho$: Suppose $\Sigma$ is a $p\times p$ matrix, so each $X_i$ is a $p\times1$ column vector. Let $P$ be the $p\times p$ matrix whose every entry is $1/p,$ and $Q=I-P,$ so $P$ projects orthogonally onto the $1$-dimensional subspace of vectors in which all entries are the same, and $Q$ projects onto its $(p-1)$-dimensional orthogonal complement. Then $\Sigma = \alpha P + \beta Q$ where $\alpha=(p-1)\rho-1$ and $\beta=1-\rho$ and $\det\Sigma= \alpha\beta^{p-1},$ and $\Sigma^{-1} = (1/\alpha)P + (1/\beta)Q.$ Then the density is$,\ldots\qquad$

$\ldots,$proportional to $$ \frac1{\sqrt{\alpha\beta^{p-1}}} \exp\left( -\frac1{2\sigma^2} x^\top\left( \frac1\alpha P+ \frac 1\beta Q \right) x \right). $$ That's with $n=1,$ but adjusting all this for $n>1$ shouldn't be too hard. Maybe more later$,\ldots\qquad$
